# Measuring page response time for different servers in web farm (HAProxy?)

Tags: iis, web-server, haproxy, response-time

I'm building out a small webserver farm (IIS7.5) to serve up an internal website. One of the things I want to measure is what the HTTP response time is between user requests and the page being served.

Given that I'm using HAProxy as a front-end load balancer, it would seem natural that HAProxy would be in an ideal place to collect this information, as it sits between every request/response. However, looking at the generated stats page, there's a lot of good information but I can't see anything about response times.

What would be the best way to go about doing this? Is this a function that HAProxy can do, or would I need some other specialist monitoring software?

Comment: AFAIK, haproxy does not fully buffers server response. I'm not sure on it though, but you need to check it. If I am right, than 'response time' would differ a lot depending on client's network speed.

Comment: You've made me think whether I care more about the response time from client->server, or the response time from HAProxy->server. Obviously the first will vary depending on client->HAProxy latency, whereas I actually care about how long it takes the server to process the response once it has received the request. So I guess I'm looking for the HAProxy->Server response time...

Comment: Ok, I'm not expert on haproxy, just suggesting you to make sure you've selected right metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HAProxy provides **very** detailed statistics about all HTTP requests. Way more than you see on the stats page.

You need to setup a syslog server listening to UDP syslog messages (e.g. on localhost). That syslog server needs to be configured to write the log messages received by HAProxy to a file (or wherever you like it). An example HAproxy configuration could look like this:

```
defaults
  # send the logs to localhost:514 via UDP, using the local0 facility
  log 127.0.0.1 local0 debug
  option httplog

  mode http
  balance roundrobin

listen farm
  bind 10.0.0.1:80

  server iis1 10.0.1.1:80
  server iis2 10.0.1.2:80
```

See section 8 of [the configuration manual](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#8) for detailed information about the log format and how to set it up.

Comment: Thanks - I'll point it at my syslog server and write a script to parse the data.

Answer (score 1):

I use `option httplog clf` for logging and capture a few extra fields, but here is a python regex I wrote for that (which might save you some time):

```
line_regex=re.compile('ny-lb[0-9]{2} (?P<HTTP_CLIENT_IP>[^ ]+) - - \[[^\]]*\] "(?P<HTTP_METHOD>[^ ]+) (?P<HTTP_URI>[^ ]+) (?P<HTTP_VERSION>\w+/\d+\.\d+)" (?P<HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE>\d{3}) (?P<HTTP_HAPROXY_BYTES_READ>\d+) "[^"]*" "[^"]*" [^ ]+ [^ ]+ "(?P<HTTP_HAPROXY_FRONTEND>[^"]+)" "(?P<HTTP_HAPROXY_BACKEND>[^"]+)" "(?P<HTTP_SERVER>[^"]+)" (?P<HTTP_HAPROXY_TQ>-?\d*) (?P<HTTP_HAPROXY_TW>-?\d*) (?P<HTTP_HAPROXY_TC>-?\d*) (?P<HTTP_HAPROXY_TR>-?\d*) (?P<HTTP_HAPROXY_TT>-?\d*) "(?P<HTTP_HAPROXY_TERM_STATE>[^"]*)" (?P<HTTP_HAPROXY_ACTCONN>-?\d*) (?P<HTTP_HAPROXY_FECONN>-?\d*) (?P<HTTP_HAPROXY_BECONN>-?\d*) (?P<HTTP_HAPROXY_SRV_CONN>-?\d*) (?P<HTTP_HAPROXY_RETRIES>-?\d*) (?P<HTTP_HAPROXY_SRV_QUEUE>-?\d*) (?P<HTTP_HAPROXY_BACKEND_QUEUE>-?\d*) "[^"]*" "[^"]*" "(?P<HTTP_REFERER>[^"]*)" "(?P<HTTP_UA>[^"]*)" "(?P<HTTP_HOST>[^"]*)" "(?P<HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR>[^"]*)"')
```

You probably want the HTTP_HAPROXY_TR field:

> Tr: server response time (HTTP mode
>   only). It's the time elapsed between
>       the moment the TCP connection was established to the server and the
>   moment
>       the server sent its complete response headers. It purely shows its
>   request
>       processing time, without the network overhead due to the data
>   transmission.
>       It is worth noting that when the client has data to send to the server,
>   for
>       instance during a POST request, the time already runs, and this can
>   distort
>       apparent response time. For this reason, it's generally wise not to
>   trust
>       too much this field for POST requests initiated from clients behind
>   an
>       untrusted network. A value of "-1" here means that the last the response
>       header (empty line) was never seen, most likely because the server
>   timeout
>       stroke before the server managed to process the request.

Answer (score 1):

No syslog needed, the CSV export function from the stats page provides all the details.

```
$ lynx -source -auth=STATSUSER:STATSPASSWORD 'http://haproxy/stats;csv' | cut -d ',' -f 2,8,61
```

Fields 2,8 and 61 will show backend's name, total sessions and avg response time in ms for the last 1024 reqs.